# Assets in Grails 2.5.0

Tags: html, grails, asset-pipeline, assets

I'm using grails version grails `2.5.x`.

Previously, by default we put `js, css, images` in `webapp/javascript, web/css, webapp/images`. Since `grails 2.3 or 2.4` (not remember exactly) those was be located in assets folder.

The problem is that I'm going to project `Metronic` theme into project. In the folder, it is divided into `assets/bla bla`, not like the structure of grails assets.

How can I import the whole project instead of fixing path of each page.

I'm looking for somthing like customer assets tag: eg. `<assets:frontend src:""/>`

Comment: That is a bit tricky. Here's an example of adding Twitter Bootstrap to be managed by the asset pipeline. It uses Grails 3 but it should work with 2.5. https://bitbucket.org/erosa/masteringgrails3/commits/8305eef8326764ab30f063477a2940fb6dfc3ea5?at=default

Comment: Thanks Rosa. It's helpful.